# Parse column as time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a time column in mixed format, e.g. 19:30 and 8:00 pm. How do I 
assign it as a uniform time format, i.e. %H:%m or %H:%m %p?

```
df["Timestamp"].head(10)


0       10:00
1    10:30 AM
2       11:00
3    11:30 AM
4       12:00
5    12:30 PM
6       13:00
7     1:30 PM
8       14:00
9       14:30
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pandas `parse_datetime`:

```
In [57]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['10:00', '9:00 AM', '10:20 PM'])).apply(lambda x: x.strftime(r'%H:%M:%S'))
Out[57]: 
0    10:00:00
1    09:00:00
2    22:20:00
```

Comment: but when I do `pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.strftime(r'%H:%M:%S')))`, it gives me error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: Your brackets are wrong. You first need to parse to datetime and after the closing bracket of `to_datetime`, add the `apply`

Comment: You were right, `df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp).apply(lambda x: x.strftime(r'%H:%M:%S'))` worked. What is `r` in `r'%H:%M:%S' ` and why is it necessary?

Comment: raw strings. they do not impose special meanings for backslashes or percent characters.

Comment: This is not a vectorised solution.